# How to make div follow scrolling smoothly with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

In my container there are sections/boxes, but the last one of these boxes should follow scrolling *when none of the other boxes are visible*.

So, when user scrolls down, he sees a normal sidebar, but when user has went down enough, sidebar ends but the last box starts to follow on the top of the screen. I have seen this a lot on different kind of sites.

My code at the moment:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $.each($('.follow-scroll'),function(){
        var eloffset = $(this).offset();
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(windowpos<eloffset.top) {
            var finaldestination = 0;
        } else {
            var finaldestination = windowpos;
        }
        $(this).stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},200);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Martti, I deleted my answer so the question will attract more viewers.

Comment: nice plugin: http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

Comment: This can now be achieved through CSS in many browsers: [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since this question is getting a lot of views and the tutorial linked in the most voted answer appears to be offline, I took the time to clean up this script.

See it live here: <kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwh3box/1/)</kbd>

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 20;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: my offset was 1518 . so i changed to `scrollTop > originalY` , and `topMargin = 200`

Comment: Easy to implement 

Comment: any advice on how to get this to offset at the bottom also?  Some browser windows I am getting the div to overlap my footer

Answer (score 52):

There's a fantastic jQuery tutorial for this at https://web.archive.org/web/20121012171851/http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/.

It replicates the Apple.com shopping cart type of sidebar scrolling. The Google query that might have served you well is "fixed floating sidebar".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this isn't a great solution if your content is centered.

Comment: This is the smoothest scrolling example I can find and is almost perfect, 1 drawback for many like mentioned above me, if the layout is centered on the page, then fixing the div doesn't have the desired affect on different size windows.  Any ideas on how to get the same affect but on centered layouts

Comment: As this question is getting a lot of views, I decided to do justice and alter the original choice of best answer (which was by myself) =)

Answer (score 19):

The solution can be boiled down to this:

```
var el=$('#follow-scroll');
var elpos=el.offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y=$(this).scrollTop();
    if(y<elpos){el.stop().animate({'top':0},500);}
    else{el.stop().animate({'top':y-elpos},500);}
});
```

I have changed the assignment of `el` because finding a single element by class is not a great habit to get in to;  if you only want one element find it by id, if you want to iterate over a collection of elements then find them by class.

*please note - my answer here refers to the accepted answer at that time (it still is the accepted answer at the moment, but has since been edited and therefore my answer no longer "boils down" what you see in @Martti Lane's answer on this page; my answer "boils down" his original, accepted, answer; you can take a look at the edit history of @Martti's answer if you're interested in what I "boiled down".)*

Comment: Thanks! I replaced the .animate methods with .css (removing ", 500") which helped duplicate the result of the selected answer.

Comment: This is definitely the more elegant solution.

Comment: thanks. good solution. tested: Firefox,Chrome,Safari (MacOsX) working perfect.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me like a charm.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() { //doc ready
    if (!($.browser == "msie" && $.browser.version < 7)) {
        var target = "#floating", top = $(target).offset().top - parseFloat($(target).css("margin-top").replace(/auto/, 0));
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            if (top <= $(this).scrollTop()) {
                $(target).addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(target).removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#floating.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

**Source:** http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: This works in IE9, Chrome, FF & Opera. Haven't checked Safari yet but hopefully will work on that.

Comment: It worked for me too, but i had a problem. i have horizontal scroll on my site as the content is very wide. When i scroll the window(vertically) the div is floating, but i can't see the full div, because the horizontal scroll disappears. any suggestion?

Comment: This is the best solution because the banner stands still without disturibing the viewer with ugly scrolling (often seen in other solutions)

Answer (score 3):

This is my final code .... (based on previous fixes, thank you big time for headstart, saved a lot of time experimenting). What bugged me was scrolling up, as well as scrolling down ... :)

it always makes me wonder how jquery can be elegant!!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //run once
    var el=$('#scrolldiv');
    var originalelpos=el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page

    //run on scroll
     $(window).scroll(function(){
        var el = $('#scrolldiv'); // important! (local)
        var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var finaldestination = windowpos+originalelpos;
        el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},500);
     });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is mine solution (hope it is **plug-n-play enough** too):

1. Copy JS code part
2. Add 'slide-along-scroll' class to element you want
3. Make pixel-perfect corrections in JS-code
4. Hope you will enjoy it!

```js
// SlideAlongScroll
var SlideAlongScroll = function(el) {
  var _this = this;
  this.el = el;
  // elements original position
  this.elpos_original = el.parent().offset().top;  
  // scroller timeout
  this.scroller_timeout;
  // scroller calculate function
  this.scroll = function() {
    // 20px gap for beauty
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() + 20;
    // targeted destination
    var finaldestination = windowpos - this.elpos_original;
    // define stopper object and correction amount
    var stopper = ($('.footer').offset().top); // $(window).height() if you dont need it
    var stophere = stopper - el.outerHeight() - this.elpos_original - 20;
    // decide what to do
    var realdestination = 0;
    if(windowpos > this.elpos_original) {
      if(finaldestination >= stophere) {
        realdestination = stophere;
      } else {
        realdestination = finaldestination;
      }
    }
    el.css({'top': realdestination });
  };
  // scroll listener
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // debounce it
    clearTimeout(_this.scroller_timeout);
    // set scroll calculation timeout
    _this.scroller_timeout = setTimeout(function() { _this.scroll(); }, 300);
  });
  // initial position (in case page is pre-scrolled by browser after load)
  this.scroll();
};
// init action, little timeout for smoothness
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide-along-scroll').each(function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function(el) { new SlideAlongScroll(el); }, 300, $(el));
  });
});
```

```css
/* part you need */
.slide-along-scroll {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
 transition: top 300ms ease-out;
 position: relative;
}
/* just demo */
div {  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.side-column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;    
}
.main-column {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
  min-height: 1200px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.body {  
  padding: 20px 0;  
}
.body:after {
  content: ' ';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;  
}
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="header">
      <h1>Your super-duper website</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="body">  
    <div class="side-column">
        <!-- part you need -->
        <div class="slide-along-scroll">
            Side menu content
            <ul>
               <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
               <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
               <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
            </ul>         
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-column">
        Main content area (1200px)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
      Footer (slide along is limited by it)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't work very well
i fixed it a little bit

```
var el = $('.caja-pago');
var elpos_original = el.offset().top;

 $(window).scroll(function(){
     var elpos = el.offset().top;
     var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
     var finaldestination = windowpos;
     if(windowpos<elpos_original) {
         finaldestination = elpos_original;
         el.stop().animate({'top':400},500);
     } else {
         el.stop().animate({'top':windowpos+10},500);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed the div to stop when it reach a certain object, so i did it like this:

```
var el = $('#followdeal');
    var elpos_original = el.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var elpos = el.offset().top;
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var finaldestination = windowpos;
        var stophere = ( $('#filtering').offset().top ) - 170;
        if(windowpos<elpos_original || windowpos>=stophere) {
            finaldestination = elpos_original;
            el.stop().animate({'top':10});
        } else {
            el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination-elpos_original+10},500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi,
I'd like to use this tecnique for my website. 

This is the structure:

    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum....
     </div>

     <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="ad">
         ADVERTISING
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar_div1">
       DIV1
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar_div2">
       DIV2
      </div>
     </div>

 <div id="footer"> </div>
    </div>

I'd like to have the #ad div to scroll with the page, but only when all the sidebar sub-divs disapper (in this case #sidebar_div1 and #sideba_div2).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This one is same on facebook:

```js
<script>
var valX = $(window).scrollTop();
function syncScroll(target){
 var valY = $(window).scrollTop();
 var difYX = valY - valX;
 var targetX = $(target).scrollTop();
 if(valY > valX){
  $(target).scrollTop(difYX);
 }
 if(difYX <= 0){
  $(target).scrollTop(-20);
 }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
 syncScroll('#demo');
})
</script>
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
#demo{
  position:fixed;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:40%;
}
#content{
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  width:60%;
  color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </p>
      </li>  
      <li>
        <p>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </li>
    <ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </p>
      </li>  
      <li>
        <p>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </p>
      </li>  
      <li>
        <p>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </p>
      </li>  
      <li>
        <p>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </p>
      </li>  
      <li>
        <p>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </li>
    <ul>
   </div>   
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a relatively simple answer for this.

I have a table that's using one of the "sticky table header" plugins to stick right below a particular div on my page, but the menu to the left of the table didn't stick (as it's not part of the table.)

For my purposes, I knew the div that needed "stickiness" was always going to start at 385 pixels below the top of the window, so I created an empty div right above that:

```
<div id="stopMenu" class="stopMenu"></div>
```

Then ran this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){   
   if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 385 ) {
    extraPadding = $(window).scrollTop() - 385;
    $('#stopMenu').css( "padding-top", extraPadding );
   } else {
     $('#stopMenu').css( "padding-top", "0" );
   }
});
```

As the user scrolls, it adds whatever the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` is to the integer `385`, then adds that value to the `stopMenu` div that's above the thing I want to stay focused.

In the event the user scrolls all the way back up, I just set the extra padding to 0.

This doesn't require the user to do anything IN CSS particularly, but it's kind of a nice effect to make a small delay, so I put the `class="stopMenu"` in as well:

```
.stopMenu {
  .transition: all 0.1s;
}
```