# How to get a jquery scroll triggered box to work

Tags: jquery, animation, triggers, scroll, position

I have a webpage on which I would like a box to appear when the user scrolls to a certain point. As this page is a blog, this point needs to be flexible.

This is my code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var navoff = $('.navigation').offset();
      $(window).scroll(function(){
          var y = $(window).scrollTop();
          var windowheight = $(window).height();
          var totalheight = navoff.top - (windowheight / 2);

        if(y > totalheight) {
            $('.box').animate({ 'bottom': '0px' });
            }else{
            $('.box').animate({ 'bottom': '-140px' });
            }
});
});
```

Navigation is the element right underneath the blog post so I figured offset would work better than figuring out when the blog content div reached the top of the screen. The code above works, the box slides out from the bottom, but there is a huge delay. On average it takes about five seconds for the script to show the box, and ten to take it away. Why the delay? And can this be made instant?

Comment: Take care when attaching functions to scroll events. That can be triggered hundreds of times/second and can lag the page. Take a look at this workaround http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery Plugin to do so.

http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

You just have to calculate the offset you want.

Also take a look at this other Topic:
[How to make div follow scrolling smoothly with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery/2178569#2178569)

Comment: After looking at that topic I took a large part of their code and was able to get it to work nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Another problem has emerged. The script only seems to run on second page load. You have to refresh the page to get it to work. `$(document).ready(function(){
    var bx = $('.box');
  var bxpos_original = $('.navigation').offset().top - 150;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      var bxpos = bx.offset().top;
      var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(windowpos>bxpos_original) {
         bx.stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'},200);
     } else {
         bx.stop().animate({'bottom':'-140px'},150);
     }
 });
});`

Comment: Can you provide a test page so we could take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've removed some of the code out of the scroll so it won't be calculated every time the user scrolls.

**EDIT:** Also use the debounce method [eduardocereto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272031/eduardocereto) suggested

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var navoff = $('.navigation').offset().top;
     var windowheight = $(window).height();
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         var y = $(window).scrollTop();
         var totalheight = navoff - (windowheight / 2);

         if(y > totalheight) {
             $('.box').animate({ 'bottom': '0px' });
         }else{
             $('.box').animate({ 'bottom': '-140px' });
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue of it taking a while to appear, but it still takes ten seconds for the thing to hide once the user scrolls up.