# How do you make a div follow as you scroll?

Tags: html, scroll

I have a div on the left hand side which includes the business hours and weather. I would like that div to scroll down and up according to how the user scrolls. So it would follow and move up and down with the page. How would I attempt this? This is my website [judystropicalgarden.com](http://judystropicalgarden.com)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make div follow scrolling smoothly with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery)

Comment: By 'follow' do you mean that it should, literally, *follow the mouse*? Or that it should simply remain visible on the screen, regardless of scrolling?

Answer (score 94):

You can either use the css property Fixed, or if you need something more fine-tuned then you need to use javascript and track the scrollTop property which defines where the user agent's scrollbar location is (0 being at the top ... and x being at the bottom)

```
.Fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#ParentContainer').scroll(function() { 
    $('#FixedDiv').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution. Very elegant. But what worked for me was setting the javascript version to bottom i.e. Setting the scrolltop value to the bottom value of the fixed div.

Comment: What if for the purpose of the demo it is `absolute` and not fixed.

Comment: @Si8 Making something absolute positioned does not ensure that the element will remain visible in the viewport at all times as the OP's question required.

Comment: I can't get the jQuery solution to work. See https://jsfiddle.net/greyshark7/hf9tmr48/2/

Comment: @PaulJones The div has to be scrollable for the scroll() function to work. You can add  **overflow: scroll;** in the css of the parent div.

Answer (score 43):

The post is old but I found a perfect CSS for the purpose and I want to share it.

> A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).

```css
    div.sticky {
        position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        background-color: green;
        border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    }
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Yes! This modern approach supersedes the other solutions in most cases.

Comment: great and helpful answer - should be accepted since now up to date

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I had been searching for

Comment: Nice - works perfectly for me

Comment: thanks this is great

Comment: `position:sticky` is not working for me. The page is really long and it is being placed down even with `top:0`

Comment: If you write some code or a full StackOverflow post we can help you, maybe is just a z-index

Answer (score 17):

Using styling from CSS, you can define how something is positioned. If you define the element as **fixed**, it will always remain in the same position on the screen at all times.

```
div
{
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `fixed` CSS position property to accomplish this.  There is a basic tutorial on this [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position).

EDIT: However, this approach is NOT supported in IE versions < IE7, and only in IE7 if it is in standards mode.  This is discussed in a little more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628265/how-to-get-positionfixed-css-to-work-in-ie-7-with-transitional-doctype).

There is also a hack, explained [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/), that shows how to accomplish fixed positioning in IE6 without affecting absolute positioning. What version of IE are you targeting your website for?

Comment: wow ok thanks for all the answers guys...does the "fixed" method work in IE as well?

Answer (score 9):

A better JQuery answer would be:

```
$('#ParentContainer').scroll(function() { 
    $('#FixedDiv').animate({top:$(this).scrollTop()});
});
```

You can also add a number after scrollTop i.e  .scrollTop() + 5 to give it buff.

A good suggestion would also to limit the duration to 100 and go from default swing to linear easing.

```
$('#ParentContainer').scroll(function() { 
    $('#FixedDiv').animate({top:$(this).scrollTop()},100,"linear");
})
```

Answer (score 6):

the **position:fixed;** property should do the work, I used it on my Website and it worked fine.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score -1):

just use an background attachment and set it to scroll in your css.

like this:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete explanation