# Can you create div that doesn't scroll as page content

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible or not:

I have a webpage with several div's of content on it, stacked one on top of the other. At the bottom, of all the content div's, I want there to be a 100px tall image (or maybe it's a DIV with a `background-image`).

When you view this page, the browser creates scrollbars so that you can scroll down the content but also so you can scroll the bottom div/image into view.

Are there CSS settings I can use on that bottom div/image so that the browser basically ignores it as content? So that the browser doesn't try to scroll down to it? I can't figure out if this is possible or not.

Alternatively, I can make the image part of the `<body>` background, but then how do I force this image to show up exactly below my content div's?  When you change the window size, the height of my content div's change, due to changing content inside of them. So I'm not sure how you can always ensure this bottom image shows up exactly after the last content div if it's a background.

**UPDATE**

Here is a link that can help illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/ojejad/2/edit

When you scroll down, the green shows up, because it's obviously part of the content of the page. Is it possible for the browser to not consider the green div part of the page content, so that the scrolling stops at the bottom of the blue?

The reason for this is that I want people to see the green image at the bottom only if their monitor is big enough that they natually see all the blue + the green without having to scroll. But if the user's monitor is too small, I don't want them to scroll to the bottom of the page and continue scrolling just to see this image because it's really supposed to be just a background image and not apart of the important content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make a div follow as you scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399537/how-do-you-make-a-div-follow-as-you-scroll)

Comment: Sounds like you need your element out of the document flow.  You could make it a pseudo-element or give it fixed positioning.  Could you provide some code/accompanying images/a demo?

Answer (score 11):

If you want something to stick to the screen use

```
position:fixed;
```

Like so:

```
div {
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/owacaq/1/edit

Edit:

If you want something to stick to its parent use

```
position:absolute;
```

On the to be sticked element and

```
position:relative;
```

On the parent.

Position absolute doesn't respect anything except the next parent with position other than static.

Example

http://jsbin.com/eceqeh/1/edit

Comment: How do I fix it to the bottom of div's that change height when I resize the browser though?

Comment: If you want it fixed to a div not the screen use position:absolute; and position:relative; on the parent element against you wish to position it.

Comment: see this http://jsbin.com/eceqeh/1/edit resize your browser, it will be always at the bottom of the blue div

Comment: See this: http://jsbin.com/ojejad/2/edit When you scroll to the bottom, the green in there. Is it possible to make it so the green does not count as content so that the scrolling stops at the bottom of the blue? I'm trying to have a background image that only shows up when someone's monitor is large enough that they see all the blue and whatever is below it without needing to scroll. Make sense now?

Comment: If its an image you could set it as background and position it at the bottom. If its more than that, use position absolute, position the blue stuff above it with z-index. That way it will be only visible when the blue doesnt exceed the screen size.

Comment: overflow hidden on the body makes so users can't scroll at all if their screen is too small to see the content. And your second link doesn't work cause the green is attached to the bottom of the page instead of the bottom of the content. I think I'm coming to the conclusion that what I am looking for isn't possible.

Comment: And Im coming to the conclusion I dont understand the question :) Last try, look up background positioning and background size properties, like conver and contain.