# R Shiny – Make wellPanel pop-up follow as you scroll with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

**PROBLEM:** R Shiny – Make wellPanel pop-up follow as you scroll with CSS

Hi Stack Users,

I've created a Shiny application that has a data table wherein when a user clicks on a row, a hidden wellPanel will pop-up beside it to show more details related to that row.

The length of the pop-up wellPanel is long but the length of the table is longer (row count non-negotiable). I would like to make the wellPanel follow as I scroll UNTIL the top part of the wellPanel reaches the top visible part of the page. At that point, the wellPanel sticks until the bottom of the page is reached (see images of preferred state below).

Using CSS `position: fixed` didn’t do the trick because above the table and the panel, there are instructions for the intended users. As a result, using `position: fixed` just permanently sticks the wellPanel to one-part of the webpage and some information gets cut out (see sample app below).

Now, I’m not a web developer/designer by background so my knowledge of CSS is very very minimal, but I had hoped that the CSS solution in this previous post ([How do you make a div follow as you scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399537/how-do-you-make-a-div-follow-as-you-scroll) / specifically: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) using `position: sticky` would work but it still didn't do it.

Hoping to hear from the experts in the community. Thanks!

Miklos

*Simplified sample of my app along with images showing preferred state below:*

**setup.R**

```
#### LOAD PACKAGES ######################
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
require(DT)

#### PREPARE DATA ######################
id <- c('10001','10002','10003','10004','10005',
        '10006','10007','10008','10009','10010',
        '10011','10012','10013','10014','10015',
        '10016','10017','10018','10019','10020',
        '10021','10022','10023','10024','10025',
        '10026','10027','10028','10029','10030',
        '10031','10032','10033','10034','10035',
        '10036','10037','10038','10039','10040'
        )

info <- c('Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info',
          'Info','Info','Info','Info','Info'
          )

info2 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info3 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info4 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info5 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info6 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info7 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info8 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info9 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info10 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info11 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info12 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info13 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info14 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info15 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)
info16 <- sample(1:100,40,replace=T)

dt <- data.table(id=id,info=info,info2=info2,
                 info3=info3,info4=info4,info5=info5,
                 info6=info6,info7=info7,info8=info8,
                 info9=info9,info10=info10,info11=info11,
                 info12=info12,info13=info13,info14=info14,
                 info15=info15,info16=info16
                 )

#### INSTANTIATE FUNCTIONS ######################
get_instructions <- function() {
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
  "
}

render_my_table <- function(dt, sel) {
  if(missing(sel)) {
    sel = list(mode='single')
  }  else {
    sel = list(mode='single', selected = sel)
  }
  return (DT::datatable(dt[, list("ID" = id, "Info"=info)], 
                        selection = sel, filter="top", 
                        options = list(sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip', 
                                       lengthChange = FALSE, 
                                       pageLength = 40)))
}

generate_popup_details <- function(user) {
  c(
    paste("Info 2: ", user$info2),
    paste("Info 3: ", user$info3),
    paste("Info 4: ", user$info4),
    paste("Info 5: ", user$info5),
    paste("Info 6: ", user$info6),
    paste("Info 7: ", user$info7),
    paste("Info 8: ", user$info8),
    paste("Info 9: ", user$info9),
    paste("Info 10: ", user$info10),
    paste("Info 11: ", user$info11),
    paste("Info 12: ", user$info12),
    paste("Info 13: ", user$info13),
    paste("Info 14: ", user$info14),
    paste("Info 15: ", user$info15),
    paste("Info 16: ", user$info16)
    )
}
```

**ui.R**

```
source("setup.R")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("My Shiny Application"),
  hr(),
  h3("Some Instructions to Users:"),
  h5(get_instructions()),
  hr(),
  mainPanel("",         
            fluidRow(
              splitLayout(div(DT::dataTableOutput('my_table')), 
                          div(
                            shinyjs::hidden(
                              wellPanel(id="my_panel", style = "position:fixed;",
                                        h3("More Information",align="center"),
                                        htmlOutput("my_popup")
                              )
                            )
                          )
              )
            )
  ) 
))
```

**server.R**

```
source("setup.R")

function(input, output, session) {

  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    render_my_table(dt)
  }, server=TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$my_table_cell_clicked, {
    row = as.numeric(input$my_table_rows_selected)
    user = dt[row]
    if(nrow(user) == 0) {
      return ()
    }
    output$my_popup <- renderUI({ 
      HTML(paste(generate_popup_details(user) ,collapse="<br/>"))
    })

    shinyjs::showElement(id= "my_panel")
  })

}
```

**PREFERRED STATE:**

*App upon load*
[image: App upon load]

*User reaches bottom of the page and wellPanel stays at the top part of the visible page*
[image: User reaches bottom of the page and wellPanel stays at the top part of the visible page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this JavaScript code:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table');
  $('#my_panel').css('top', tbl.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    var tbltop = tbl.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var x = tbltop < 0 ? 0 : tbltop;
    $('#my_panel').css('top', x);
  });
});"
```

To include in the app like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  useShinyjs(),
  ......
```

(Do not change anything else).

[image]

Comment: Worked wonders! Was planning to raise to RStudio why the 'position:  sticky' CSS option doesn't work for Shiny, but this saved a lot of my time. Thank you so much Stéphane! Enjoy the weekend.