# Image Hovering On Webpage

Tags: image, hover, html

I'm trying to make a chat image hover on the webpage without any luck. You can view what I want it to do by going to Longo Toyota's website here. http://www.longotoyota.com

The chat image hovers over the webpage and scrolls with this user. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work? I've searched for a while and all I can come up with is how to make a rollover image which isn't what I want to do at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery, this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same feature on one of my project. I made a fixed or floating position of a menu on one of my sites.

the solution I made to make this work came from this site

http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm

it's all about css.
if you want to pop up something onHover use javascript or any framework(I prefer using jQuery)

cheers.:)

Answer (score 0):

a css

```
position: fixed;
```

is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into using fixed positions and z-index