# Div - Focus on scrolling screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<div id="leftpane">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
</div>
<div style="float:right" id="display_div"></div>
```

I have a page with a two-column layout, a left pane and a right pane (= main content area). The left pane has divs (one,two,three etc..) which are like menu items. The corresponding content for the selected div is displayed in the right pane.

What I want to do (onload): the first div must be highlighted in the left pane and the corresponding content displayed in the right pane. As I keep scrolling down the left pane of div's , the focus should keep shifting to the lower divs gradually and their contents begin to be displayed respectively on the right pane.

How can I possibly achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: use jsfiddle to explain your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery

Comment: @DavidJashi : the above question refers to a max limit to scroll down and then following it , mine refers to the focusing  the first div by default and displaying it's contents and subsequently displaying other divs contents as the page is left pane is scrolled down and other divs come into focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a plugin for what you describe. You could go with few lines of javascript instead:

```js
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    var delta = 50;
    $('#leftpane div').each(function(i) {
        var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(rect.top >= 0  && rect.top < window.innerHeight - delta)
        {
            $('#display_div').html($(this).html());
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WzUZw/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WzUZw/1/).

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins available for this functionality.

The [Scrollspy](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) plugin that is bundled with Twitter Bootstrap is a good example.

Also available for [jQuery](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy) and [MooTools](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

## HTML

```
<ul id="top-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo">Foo</a>
<a id="bar">Bar</a>
<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript you can simply attach handlers to divisions for mouse movement and to window for scroll events:

```js
if (!window.addEventListener) { // for compatibility with IE6-8
    window.addEventListener = function (type, listener, useCapture) {
        attachEvent('on' + type, function () {
            listener(event)
        });
    }
}

var display, divs, divslen;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    display = document.getElementById('display_div');
    divs = document.getElementById('leftpane').getElementsByTagName('div');
    divslen = divs.length; // collection length
    for (var i = 0; i < divslen; i++) {
        divs[i].onmouseover = function () {
            display.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        };
    }
}, false);
window.addEventListener('scroll', update_display_div, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', update_display_div, false);

function update_display_div() {
    var updated = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < divslen; i++) {
        var rect = divs[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (!updated && rect.top > -20) {
            display.innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML; //show topmost div
            updated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdHqG/2/)

Thanks to Michal Klouda for reference to getBoundingClientRect() function.