# Button that scrolls with the page

Tags: button, scroll

I want to create a button like on www.bamboohr.com that will follow as you scroll. Help?

I am an amateur with html, and I am assuming this is css/js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make div follow scrolling smoothly with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

Try `style="position: fixed"` on the button.

Answer (score 4):

The way their floater's working is by a mixture of

- jQuery to move the floater (read keep it at the same position) based on the scrollTop
- [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), to make the movement smooth

Of course we need an element with `position: absolute;` and some x and y value and possibly `z-index` to make sure it's placed in front of the other elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="floater">FLOATING BUTTON</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#floater {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var floaterHeight = $('#floater').outerHeight(true);
    //true so the function takes margins into account
    var fromBottom = 20;

    var top = winScrollTop + winHeight - floaterHeight - fromBottom;
    $('#floater').css({'top': top + 'px'});
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/sc9jycd7/2/)

Comment: Thanks man!  Sorry I have been away sick.  I really appreciate the help!