# Smoothly Moving a div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, transform, parallax

I would like to continuously shift a png (or, its containing div) as I scroll down, as scrollTop goes from one value to another.  Basically, I would like to move it vertically via "transform: "translate" from -600% at scrollTop is 1165 to 550% at scrollTop is 1700.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
 <div id="droplet">
     <img src="img/drop06.png">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#droplet{
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate(76.5%,-600%);
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    var difference = (11.5*(scrollTop-1165)/(1700 - 1165))-600;

    // (1) $('#droplet').css('transform: translate(76.5%',+difference+'%');

    // (2) $('#droplet').css({transform, 'translate(76.5%,'+ difference +'%)'});

    // (3) $('#droplet').css({transform: 'translate(76.5%,' + difference +'%)'});

    // (4) $('#droplet').css('transform','translate(76.5%,'+difference+'%)');

    });
});
```

(1) through (4) are my attempts, none of which do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177983/how-to-make-div-follow-scrolling-smoothly-with-jquery

Comment: @Thavo These are not exactly what I am looking for.  From what I could see, these are animations that make the target "jump" from one location to another upon scroll down.  I suppose I didn't describe what I need well enough.  I would like something that is similar to the parallax effect, where the speed of the moving div is in direct proportion to the speed of the scroll, instead of "I scroll to where I'm going and afterward the element 'jumps'."